# Why jdt weaving does not work for launch a Eclipse Application from host Eclipse which jdt weaving works?

Tags: eclipse, scala

I was struggling with this for a long time.

I installed Scala eclipse plugin in my eclipse mars, and the eclipse's JDT weaving is successful. But when I want to run a new Eclipse Application, it will open a new eclipse and keep asking me: JDT Weaving is disabled, activate it and restart Eclipse.

I tried: using a fresh Eclipse, deleting .p2 folder, modify the configuration/config.ini file... I even tried to use [equinox-weaving-launcher](https://github.com/scala-ide/equinox-weaving-launcher). Just no luck.

Anybody can tell me whats the key place to look for a child eclipse and why the JDT weaving is not working?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolving this by editing configuration/config.ini file's following line from:

`osgi.framework.extensions=reference\:file\:org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state_1.0.100.v20150402-1551.jar`

to

`osgi.framework.extensions=reference\:file\:org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state_1.0.100.v20150402-1551.jar,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.hook_1.1.100.weaving-hook-20140821.jar`

and then load my eclipse application by loading from this host eclipse's config.ini file instead of creating by itself.

But one more questions still there, if the origin config.ini file don't have that `org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.hook_1.1.100.weaving-hook-20140821.jar`, how the JDT weaving are success on the host Eclipse.